# Building an app using HTML CSS JavaScript on a touch compact device?

Tags: embedded, raspberry-pi, user-interface

I'm a web developer who uses HTML/CSS/JS to write applications with awesome user interfaces using frameworks like reactjs and nodejs for browsers. I can build the same apps using the same code to create apps on desktop using Electron platform.

What I need right now is to use the same technology to create a compact tablet-like device with touch screen that boots up with my html/css/js app I created using web technology.

I already have some experience with Arduino and electronic basics but none of them have a solid high performance processor/microcontroller and memory that JS need.

I came across Raspberry Pi(connected to a touch-LCD) and have some ideas but I'm not sure if it can fit my needs at the end.

Is there an easy way to do this or a wrapped-up solution with high performance smartphone-like webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are many solutions. I think what you need is more generally called a Single Board Computer. Depending on the CPU power you needs (you're the one to know), you could compare the different available solutions on the market on this wikipedia page Comparison of [single-board computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_single-board_computers).

If you need help to evaluate the needed performance, you could ask in another question I guess it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this dependent on the complexity of your application, how much data, if it is a standalone application or networked etc.

I have certainly implemented node.js on Raspberry Pi. I'm sure, as long as you are considerate of the resources available, you will have no worry with using a front end-frame work such as ember or angular.